# Order of keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
{'a': 'first', 'b': 'second'}
```

However, I need the dictionary in a different order:

```
{'b': 'second', 'a': 'first'}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Ok, my fault, I'll read documentation. I just print it and it was out by specific order by chance. I thought it has something to do with a way it is written. Like php's array.

Comment: @Qiao This is actually a good question. I was like "oh, that'll be easy to answer with the documentation" -- it isn't. This "trivial fact" seems to be assumed knowledge in most places. The best I can find (in OrderedDict, chapter 8.3) is "An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted.".

Comment: Ahh, there it is: "It is best to think of a dictionary as an *unordered* set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)." from [5.5 Data Structures in the Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: -1.  Searching StackOverflow for "python dictionary order" easily finds the answer.  You should at least try *something* before posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what order does python display dictionary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458169/in-what-order-does-python-display-dictionary-keys)

Comment: @pst: Also [Library Reference, Ch. 5 "Built-in Types"](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items): <quote>CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.</quote>

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, I was looking for "how to change dictionary order?", not for "is it possible to change dictionary order?". They are different questions, though have the same answer.

Comment: @Qiao: If they have the same answer, then they're dupes. The idea is to get all the answers in one place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse order of keys in python dict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455606/how-to-reverse-order-of-keys-in-python-dict)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Dictionaries are **not ordered**. So there is no way to do it.

If you have python2.7+, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` - in this case you could retrieve the item list using `.items()` and then reverse it and create a new `OrderedDict` from the reversed list:

```
>>> od = OrderedDict((('a', 'first'), ('b', 'second')))
>>> od
OrderedDict([('a', 'first'), ('b', 'second')])
>>> items = od.items()  # list(od.items()) in Python3
>>> items.reverse()
>>> OrderedDict(items)
OrderedDict([('b', 'second'), ('a', 'first')])
```

If you are using an older python version you can get a backport from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/

Comment: Exactly, both dictionaries in your example are equivalent.

Comment: Sorted and ordered are different thing. `OrderedDict` isn't sorted, can't be sorted manually and no data structure in Python is a sorted data structure (i.e. always automatically sorted).

Comment: That's what I meant. Edited my answer for clarity though.

Comment: @Roxy Oxymoron But an OrderedDict can be created from a sorted list. The question isn't: "how can I created a dict that is *always* sorted?"

Comment: Does not work in Python 3.4. The line items = od.items() returns an ItemsView object, which does not have a reverse() function.

Comment: Updated my answer to mention how to do it in Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

Dictionaries don't have order.

You can get the keys, order them however you like, then iterate the dictionary values that way.

```
keys = myDict.keys()
keys = sorted(keys)  # order them in some way
for k in keys:
   v = myDict[k]
```

Comment: I think you wanted `keys.sort()`. `sorted()` returns a new list but does not modify the passed object.

Answer (score 4):

You can't; `dict`s are unsortable. Use an `OrderedDict` if you need an ordered dictionary.

Comment: `dict` is sortable (you can always apply `sorted` to it) but the default order of keys cannot be influenced.

Comment: what if the keys are numeric & inserted incrementally `eg:1,2,3,....10`. So in this case, the order is preserved right?