# Build query string using urlencode python

Tags: python, dictionary, urllib

I am trying to build a url so that I can send a get request to it using `urllib` module.

Let's suppose my `final_url` should be

```
url = "www.example.com/find.php?data=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com&search=Generate+value"
```

Now to achieve this I tried the following way:

```
>>> initial_url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
>>> search = "Generate+value"
>>> params = {"data":initial_url,"search":search}
>>> query_string = urllib.urlencode(params)
>>> query_string
'search=Generate%2Bvalue&data=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com'
```

Now if you compare my `query_string` with the format of `final_url` you can observer two things

1) The order of params are reversed instead of `data=()&search=` it is `search=()&data=`

2) `urlencode` also encoded the `+` in `Generate+value`

I believe the first change is due to the random behaviour of dictionary. So, I though of using [`OrderedDict` to reverse the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083531/python-reverse-dictionary-order). As, I am using `python 2.6.5` I did

```
pip install ordereddict
```

But I am not able to use it in my code when I try

```
>>> od = OrderedDict((('a', 'first'), ('b', 'second')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined
```

So, my question is what is the correct way to use `OrderedDict` in python 2.6.5 and how do I make `urlencode` ignores the `+` in `Generate+value`.

Also, is this the correct approach to build `URL`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about encoding the `+` it should be restored on the server after unescaping the url. The order of named parameters shouldn't matter either.

Considering OrderedDict, it is not Python's built in. You should import it from `collections`:

```
from urllib import urlencode, quote
# from urllib.parse import urlencode # python3
from collections import OrderedDict

initial_url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
search = "Generate+value"
query_string = urlencode(OrderedDict(data=initial_url,search=search))
url = 'www.example.com/find.php?' + query_string
```

**if your python is too old** and does not have OrderedDict in the module `collections`, use:

```
encoded = "&".join( "%s=%s" % (key, quote(parameters[key], safe="+")) 
    for key in ordered(parameters.keys()))
```

Anyway, the order of parameters should not matter.

Note the `safe` parameter of `quote`. It prevents `+` to be escaped, but it means , server will interpret `Generate+value` as `Generate value`. You can manually escape `+` by writing `%2B`and marking `%` as safe char:

Comment: I tried `from collections import OrderedDict` but now I am getting `ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict`. I am using python `2.6.5`

Comment: It should be available from pyton 2.4. What do jou get if you execute `import collections`?

Comment: I can successfully import collection no error is thrown. I though `OrderedDict` was introduced from python 2.7 onwards.

Answer (score 3):

First, the order of parameters in a http request should be completely irrelevant. If it isn't then the parsing library on the othe side is doing something wrong.

Second, of course the `+` is encoded. `+` is used as placeholder for a space in an encoded url, so if yor raw string contains a `+`, this has to be escaped. `urlencode` expects an unencoded string, you can't pass it a string that is already encoded.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I didn't checked before asking my mistake.

Comment: with kind regards, the order of the parameters is not irrelevant. in case a parameter is present more than once, it should be regarded as a list, with positional relevance of it's elements.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments on the question and other answers:

1. If you want to preserve order with `urllib.urlencode`, submit an ordered sequence of k/v pairs instead of mapping(dict).  when you pass in a dict,  `urlencode` just calls `foo.items()` to grab an iterable sequence.

`` # urllib.urlencode accepts a mapping or sequence
    # the output of this can vary, because `items()` is called on the dict
    urllib.urlencode({"data": initial_url,"search": search})
    # the output of this will not vary
    urllib.urlencode((("data", initial_url), ("search", search))) ``

you can also pass in a secondard `doseq` argument to adjust how iterable values are handled.

2. The order of parameters is not irrelevant.  take these two urls for example:

   https://example.com?foo=bar&bar=foo
   https://example.com?bar=foo&foo=bar

   A http server should consider the order of these parameters irrelevant, but a function designed to compare URLs would not.  In order to safely compare urls, these params would need to be sorted.

   However, consider duplicate keys:

   https://example.com?foo=3&foo=2&foo=1

The URI specs support duplicate keys, but don't address precedence or ordering.

In a given application, these could each trigger different results and be valid as well:

```
https://example.com?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3
https://example.com?foo=1&foo=3&foo=2
https://example.com?foo=2&foo=3&foo=1
https://example.com?foo=2&foo=1&foo=3
https://example.com?foo=3&foo=1&foo=2
https://example.com?foo=3&foo=2&foo=1
```

1. The `+` is a reserved character that represents a space in a urlencoded form (vs `%20` for part of the path). `urllib.urlencode` escapes using `urllib.quote_plus()`, not `urllib.quote()`.  The OP most likely wanted to just do this:

`initial_url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    search = "Generate value"
    urllib.urlencode((("data", initial_url), ("search", search)))`

Which produces:

`data=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com&search=Generate+value`

as the output.