# How to order a dictionary by the value types without importing modules

Tags: python, string, methods, dictionary

I'm trying to sort this dictionary:

```
dictionary = {24249:"t",390395:"b",90395:"q",5939:"z",1:"k",3909:"a"}
```

I've seen people use lambda to do this, but I'm trying to solve this problem by using only the dict methods.

I was able to order the values:

```
ordered = sorted(dictionary.values())
```

but I don't know how to access the keys of the ordered values.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the keys" ?

Comment: @JonClements If I wanted to print out the contents of the dictionary in a loop, wouldn't I need the keys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse dictionary order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083531/reverse-dictionary-order)

Answer (score 3):

In Python, dictionaries are inherently unordered. You can turn the dictionary into a list of tuples if you want:

```
result = sorted(dictionary.items(),key=lambda x: x[1])
```

which will give you:

```
[(3909, 'a'), (390395, 'b'), (1, 'k'), (90395, 'q'), (24249, 't'), (5939, 'z')]
```

Comment: Right, you'd need to change the data structure to a list or somesuch.

Comment: +1, was just about to post that. You can iterate over `result` like a dict too.  E.G. `for key, value in result: print key, value`

Comment: I've seen a solution similar to this, but I was trying to avoid using lambda.

Comment: @JonnyLamp : Use `itemgetter`, but I guess you don't want that too since it gets imported from `operator` module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects). Sure, this will require that you import a class from the `collections` module, but bear in mind - the "normal" dictionary doesn't maintain the order of its entries:

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

For example, here's a dictionary using sorted keys for insertion order, meaning: if you iterate over it, the entries will appear sorted by the key:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dictionary = { 24249:'t', 390395:'b', 90395:'q', 5939:'z', 1:'k', 3909:'a' }

OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

=> OrderedDict([(1, 'k'), (3909, 'a'), (5939, 'z'),
                (24249, 't'), (90395, 'q'), (390395, 'b')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that *does not import modules* and *does not uses lambda* to sort a dictionary by value:

```
dictionary = {24249: "t", 390395: "b", 90395: "q", 5939: "z", 1: "k", 3909: "a"}
keys_sorted_by_value = sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
```

To print in the sorted order:

```
for key in keys_sorted_by_value:
    print("key: {key}, value: {value}".format(key=key, value=dictionary[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that way :

```
dictionary = {24249:"t",390395:"b",90395:"q",5939:"z",1:"k",3909:"a"}

val = dictionary.values()
val
['a', 'b', 'k', 'q', 't', 'z']

[{v:k for k,v in dictionary.items()}[i] for i in val]
[3909, 390395, 1, 90395, 24249, 5939]
```