# Reverse a python dictionary ordered pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, reverse

This question has been asked many times, and I searched diligently to no avail. 
Here is an example of my question:

`dict = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"}`

The output I am looking for is as below:

`dict = {"c":"3", "b":"2", "a":"1"}`

I am really unsure how to attack this, as here is my current code:

```
def reorder(a):
       clean = {}
       pair = {}
       i = 0
       for k, v in a.iteritems():
             pair = a.popitem()
             #Do stuff here
       return clean
```

What I am currently doing is grabbing the tuple pair as a key/value, as these need to remain the same. I am not sure how to insert this pair in a reverse order though.

Comment: Your diligent search missed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083531/order-of-keys-in-python-dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is unordered *by definition*:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered set of key: value pairs**, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

Therefore, your question cannot be answered and you should consider using a different data structure. Perhaps an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which *can* be reversed:

```
>>> import collections
>>> dict = collections.OrderedDict([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
>>> collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list(dict.items())))
OrderedDict([(5, 6), (3, 4), (1, 2)])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a seriously fast answer. Unfortunately at this time, I can't change the data structure but its starting to sound as if this is quite impossible to do. Can this be done manually?

I was thinking up above in my code, is to grab the tuple, and send it to another function. Use that function to store the tuple in memory, assign it to a value such as 0, 1, 2, 3 and use a for loop to insert the tuples backwards into a new dictionary

Comment: As I said, there is **no possible way** to keep using a dictionary and "reverse" it, because the word "reverse" has no meaning in a dictionary... You can put the items in a `list` and reverse that, if it helps...

Comment: What about creating a new dict and having the key/value pairs inserted in a specified way?

Comment: You are trying to eat soup with a fork... Please take my advice.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `dict` object of python is a hashtable, so It have no order.
but if you only want to get a list is order you can use `sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)` method.

`def order(dic):
   return sorted(dic.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)`