# Reverse Dictionary function

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

Hello I am having trouble making a function that reverses any dictionary given to it but without any special libraries. For example

```
D = {one:uno, two:dos}
```

would return that dictionary as `D = {uno:one, dos:two}`

I am asking the reverse order for both the key and value not just key, this is very different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse order of keys in python dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455606/how-to-reverse-order-of-keys-in-python-dict)

Comment: how mine is different

Comment: how is it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
```

Example:

```
d = {'one':'uno', 'two':'dos'}
result = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
print(result) # prints - {'uno': 'one', 'dos': 'two'}
```

What is happening here?

- `(v,k) for k,v in d.items()` - You first iterate over all the (key, value) pairs in the dictionary and create tuples of (value, key).
- Then you call `dict()` to create dictionary from the tuples.

Comment: how about the .items what does this function do