# How to reverse the (key,value)'s order of a dict in the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value

for example I have this Dictionary

a = {'Sara': 3, 'Marie': 1, 'James': 1, 'Alex': 1}
I know that I can print the (key,value) one by one with such this code:

```
for key,value in a.items():
print(key,value)
```

and the result would be something like this:

```
Sara 3
Marie 1
James 1
Alex 1
```

**My Question** is how can I reserve this order to :

```
Alex 1
James 1
Marie 1
Sara 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455606/how-to-reverse-order-of-keys-in-python-dict

Comment: ``sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x : (x[1], x[0]))``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key,value in list(a.items())[::-1]:
    print(key,value)
```

Convert that a.items() into a list
and then switch the order by adding [::-1]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'Sara': 3, 'Marie': 1, 'James': 1, 'Alex': 1} 
sort_a= sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)
for i in sort_a:
   print(i[0],i[1])
```

Try this