# reverse nested dicts using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I already referred these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455606/how-to-reverse-order-of-keys-in-python-dict), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568673/inverse-dictionary-lookup-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict).

I have a sample dict like as shown below

```
t = {'thisdict':{
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
},
'thatdict':{
  "af": "jfsak",
  "asjf": "jhas"}}
```

I am trying to reverse a python dictionary.

My code looks like below

```
print(type(t))
inv = {v:k  for k,v in t.items()} # option 1 - error here
print(inv) 
frozenset(t.items())  # option 2 - error here
```

Instead I get the below error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Following the suggestion from post above, I tried `frozen set`, but still I get the same error

I expect my output to be like as below

```
t = {'thisdict':{
  "Ford":"brand",
  "Mustang":"model",
  1964:"year"
},
'thatdict':{
  "jfsak":"af",
  "jhas":"asjf"}}
```

Comment: What is the expected reversed dict?

Comment: Does this work for you? `reversed_t = {key: t[key] for key in reversed(t.keys())}`

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted continuously without any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested dict comprehension:

```py
t = {'thisdict': {"brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964},
     'thatdict': {"af": "jfsak", "asjf": "jhas"}}

output = {k_out: {v: k for k, v in d.items()} for k_out, d in t.items()}
print(output)
# {'thisdict': {'Ford': 'brand', 'Mustang': 'model', 1964: 'year'}, 'thatdict': {'jfsak': 'af', 'jhas': 'asjf'}}
```